# insert mongodb user id inside another users schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Having trouble with the following schema

```
const FriendRequestSchema = new Schema({
    requester: {
        _id: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
        }
    },
    profilePicture: String,
    pending: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    }
})
```

the way i create a new friend request

```
const friendRequest = new FriendRequest({
    requester: {
        _id: req.user._id
    },
    profilePicture: req.user.profilePicture
})
```

results object

```
    {
        "pending": true,
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5ab4fdb07525fd6880d1a6b9"
        },
        "profilePicture": "/assets/profile_icons/glasses.png"
    }
```

now the problem is:

1. im missing the requester field
2. the id field is always different and dosent save the requester id

how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try change you schema like this:

```
 requester: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            ref: 'User', // depends on how you called user schema
        },
```

Usage:

```
const friendRequest = new FriendRequest({
    requester: req.user._id,
    profilePicture: req.user.profilePicture
})
```